# Wordpress Javascript / jQuery conflicts

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm really stuck on a problem. I have already searched Google and even asked on twitter but no avail. My problem is with Wordpress, when trying to use thickbox and jQuery slider on the same page my slider becomes static.

(Without the jQuery script)
If I remove the jQuery script for {Nivo slider} then my lightbox works.

(Without thickbox javascript)
When I don't use the thickbox javascript my slider works.

(The Problem)
When using both scripts thickbox overwrites the slider causing it to show the images below one another (not hidden) and the slider stops working all together.

However I have tested using the two scripts on Drupal on my local host and they work fine together however on Wordpress it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [wp_enqueue_script](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) which talks about using WordPress's version of jQuery and also make sure that YOUR jQuery is being run in [noConflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) mode.

Comment: More than likely the issue will be noConflict()

Comment: Slight problem :S in no conflict mode thickbox stops working. However the slider is working.

Comment: You got any links to your files?

Comment: Give me 5 mins ill just upload it to my own host instead of the clients so you can see the problem.

Comment: Do you have an email address that I can send the link to ?

Comment: The easiest way to replicate the problem on wordpress is to install easy nivo slider and thick box plugins, it has the same problem.

On the current theme I'm developing I'm using the easy nivo slider plugin and the thickbox written into the header.php file.